# Modify the return value of a sequelize operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

What I am aiming to do is find a record in my db, call an api with that record and return the value of the api call rather than the record.

I am easily able to do this using the following code.

```
const tempRecord = await Record.findOne({
    where: { token: req.params.token },
  });

const updatedRecord = await callApi(tempRecord.id);

return res.json({updatedRecord})
```

Now this is fine and it works but I'm repeating this a ton of times throughout the app and I'm wondering if there is a way to return this directly from the Model.find so I can dry up the codebase and prevent errors down the line.

So far I've tried adding a hook. It calls the api and get's the data as I expect but still returns the original record.

```
Record.addHook("afterFind", async (obj, options) => {
  return await callApi(obj.token);
});
```

Comment: Usually such problems are solved by using `repository pattern` where you place all needed method like `getRecordIdByToken` and so on inside a repository. That way all other code will not be aware of details of Sequelize calls and will use repository methods only.